# "WordPress installations is currently out of date" problem with difficult situation

Tags: wp-admin, upgrade, configuration, support, customization

[NOTE] I had asked [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-installations-is-currently-out-of-date-problem-in-login-wp-admin) question in wordpress.org's support forum one month ago. But I didn't get any feedback there. And I am not sure whether or not this is right place to ask this question. But I hope there are developers from WordPress on StackOverflow to look at my question and give me some hint.

**My problem is :**

Few years ago I had got the opportunity to have a blog on my own domain name - (www.ganeshtiwari.com.np) , which uses version 2.7.* of wordpress. It was an free offer from a organization  called rtrc.org (Redsun Technologies & Research Center, Nepal).

The organization (rtrc.org) is out of business and they have closed every support. I found that my website is hosted from ( Hopkinsville - Kentucky - United States)- according to geo-ip locator.

**But** now this message appears even when I open the main page or wp-admin page and I can do nothing there. The big problem is, the upgrade to new version cannot be done (now and then- never); even there was no feature/setting enabled for add plugins and change the theme.

```
We were checking our accounts and found that one or more of your WordPress installations is currently out of date. It's critical that you update WordPress, as its current version has some severe security vulnerabilities that put your website and hosting account in jeopardy.

We strongly recommend an upgrade to the latest stable verion of WordPress by following these steps:

1. Access the directory in which WordPress is installed via Webshell within your control panel or using your FTP client
2. Be sure to turn on the "show hidden" option and look for an .htaccess file in your WordPress directory. Delete or rename this .htaccess file
3. If you find an .htaccess.UNPROTECTED file, rename it to .htaccess
4. Login to your WordPress dashboard as an Administrator
5. At the top of the dashboard, WordPress will alert you to a new version; click the "update now" link
6. Follow the update wizard to complete the upgrade (The "Upgrade Automatically" option on the second step is recommended. You can read more about this feature here.)
7. We recommend that you further improve the security of your WordPress installation using 10 Useful WordPress Security Tweaks
8. Reset your Administrator user password

If you have any questions, feel free to contact us via phone, ticket, or chat!

Thank you!
```

This is not only the problem of mine, there were more than 1000 person who opened the free domain from that organization.

I want to know is there any way(fixing the code by wordpress admin) to avoid this error message and let me in?

Comment: This message doesn't come from WordPress and it's unlikely that WP is capable of overriding something hosting enforces.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you really think this error message is from hosting service?

Comment: According to suggestion from m0r7if3r's answer, i have sent an email to hosting service. And waiting for response.

Comment: It's not from WP itself, which leaves third party code or hosting. By the way it's formulated I think hosting is most likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, someone has to be hosting it, so I recommend tracking them down. I've taken the liberty of doing this for you (using [WhoIsHostingThis?](http://www.whoishostingthis.com/ganeshtiwari.com.np)). Your host is [IX Web Hosting](http://www.ixwebhosting.com/), contact their customer support and see if you can either get them to do the upgrade for you or, preferably, get them to give you admin access to your site.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have sent an email to their customer support. I will keep updating you too.

Comment: never heard of whoishostingthis.com . thanks again